# Django APIClient test case returns 400 but postman works

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I have these test cases in my `tests.py`

```
"""Unit tests for client application."""

from django.test import TestCase
from rest_framework.test import APIClient
# Create your tests here.

class ClientTestCase(TestCase):
    api_client = APIClient()
    def test_get_clients(self):
        response = self.api_client.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/client/clients/')
        self.assertEqual(int(response.status_code), 200)

    def test_add_client(self):
        response = self.api_client.post(
            path='http://127.0.0.1:8000/client/clients/',
            data={
                'name': 'Jon Snow',
                'age': 18,
                'gender': 'M',
                'address': 'night watch wall',
                'phone_number': '+9290078601',
                'email': 'jon@nightwatch.com',
            },
            content_type='application/json'
        )
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 201)
```

When I run these tests through command

```
python manage.py test --debug-mode client/ -v 3
```

`test_get_clients` succeeds and `test_add_client` fails as the API returns `400`.
When I hit the same API I am hitting in `test_add_client` through `postman`, it returns the expected result.
The body of `postman` API is

```
{
    "name": "Bruce Wayne",
    "age" : 23,
    "gender" : "M",
    "address" : "abc asdasd asdasd asdada",
    "phone_number" : "+92 3242225259",
    "email" : "abc@xyz.com"
}
```

and in header there is `Conent-Type:'application/json` as I am already specifying in my test case.
What might I be missing here? The output of running test case is not giving any insight at all.

Comment: Use `rest_framework.test.APITestCase` instead of Django's TestCase. It already uses the `APIClient` by default and other customizations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to `json.dump` your data:

```
import json

def test_add_client(self):
    response = self.api_client.post(
        path='http://127.0.0.1:8000/client/clients/',
        data=json.dumps({
            'name': 'Jon Snow',
            'age': 18,
            'gender': 'M',
            'address': 'night watch wall',
            'phone_number': '+9290078601',
            'email': 'jon@nightwatch.com',
        }),
        content_type='application/json'
    )
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 201)
```

Comment: While you are here, I have another question IF you have a moment. So `test_add_client` created a `client` in test database, right? What will it's `pk` be? It should be `0` or `1` right because it destroys test database every time. But I am unable to succeed on my next test case of getting a `client` against this `pk`. It says `404`.